# how to make Navigation or top search bar like Myntra

Tags: html, css, reactjs, bootstrap-4

am trying to making a simple UI in their I stuck, I want full width my input type but its showing short, can anyone tell me how can I make full it, and also I want responsive in mobile and desktop mode

[image: i want like this]

[image: My UI is]

> Navbar.js

This is the navbar.js file where I wrote my UI part

```
import React from 'react'
    import './Navbar.css';
    import SearchOutlinedIcon from '@material-ui/icons/SearchOutlined';
    
    
    const Navbar = () => {
        return (
            <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light shadow-sm p-3  bg-white ">
                <div className="container">
                    <a class="navbar-brand" href=""><img src="https://imgeng.jagran.com/images/2021/jan/Myntra-805x530-1-700x4611611985286383.jpg" alt="Mynta" className="coco mr-5" /></a>
                    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
                    </button>
    
                    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
                        <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
                            <li class="nav-item ">
                                <a class="nav-link mr-2" href="#">MEN</a>
                            </li>
                            <li class="nav-item">
                                <a class="nav-link mr-2" href="#">WOMEN</a>
                            </li>
                            <li class="nav-item">
                                <a class="nav-link mr-2" href="#">KIDS</a>
                            </li>
                            <li class="nav-item">
                                <a class="nav-link mr-2" href="#">HOME & LIVING</a>
                            </li>
                            <li class="nav-item">
                                <a class="nav-link mr-2" href="#">OFFERS</a>
                            </li>
    
                        </ul>
                        {/* <div className='sidebar_search'>
                            <div className='sidebar_searchContainer'>
                                <SearchOutlinedIcon />
                                <input type='text' placeholder='Search for products brands and more' />
                            </div>
                        </div> */}
    
                        <div class="form-group has-search">
                            <span class="fa fa-search form-control-feedback"></span>
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search for Products Branda and More" />
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
    
            </nav>
        )
    }
    
    export default Navbar;
```

> style.css

This is the style.css file where I wrote some css

```
@media (min-width: 1200px) {
    .container{
        max-width: 1400px;
    }
}

.coco{
    width: 60px;
}

.nav-item{
    font-weight: bold;
    color: black;
}

.nav-item, .nav-link {
    font-size: 17px;
    color: black;
}


.has-search .form-control {
    padding-left: 2.375rem;
}

.has-search .form-control-feedback {
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 2;
    display: block;
    width: 2.375rem;
    height: 2.375rem;
    line-height: 2.375rem;
    text-align: center;
    pointer-events: none;
    color: #aaa;
    
}

input[type="text"] {
    outline: none;
    box-shadow:none !important;
    border:1px solid #ccc !important;
    }
/* .sidebar_search{
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    height: 39px;
    padding: 10px;
    background-color: #f0f0f0;
    margin-right: 100px;
    width: 100%;
}



.sidebar_searchContainer > input {
    border: none;
    margin-left: 10px;
    outline: none;
    background-color:#f0f0f0;
} */
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you could try this code:

CSS (not big changes)

```
@media (min-width: 1200px) {
    .container{
        max-width: 1400px;
    }
}

.coco{
    width: 60px;
    /*border: 1px solid blue;*/
}

.nav-item{
    font-weight: bold;
    color: black;
}

.nav-item, .nav-link {
    font-size: 17px;
    color: black;
}


.has-search .form-control {
    padding-left: 2.375rem;
}

.has-search .form-control-feedback {
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 2;
    display: block;
    width: 2.375rem;
    height: 2.375rem;
    line-height: 2.375rem;
    text-align: center;
    pointer-events: none;
    color: #aaa;

}

input[type="text"] {
    outline: none;
    box-shadow:none !important;
    border:1px solid #ccc !important;
}
```

HTML (some changes)

```
<div class="container-fluid">

    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light shadow-sm p-3  bg-white ">
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="">
            <img src="https://imgeng.jagran.com/images/2021/jan/Myntra-805x530-1-700x4611611985286383.jpg" alt="Mynta" class="coco mr-5" />
        </a>
        <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
            <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button>

        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
            <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto flex-grow-1">
                <li class="nav-item ">
                    <a class="nav-link mr-2" href="#">MEN</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link mr-2" href="#">WOMEN</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link mr-2" href="#">KIDS</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link mr-2" href="#">HOME & LIVING</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link mr-2" href="#">OFFERS</a>
                </li>

            </ul>

            <div class="form-group has-search flex-grow-1">
                <span class="fa fa-search form-control-feedback"></span>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search for Products Branda and More" />
            </div>
        </div>

    </nav>
</div>
```

**Explanation**

The changes made are as follows:

- in the tag with the class coco, I have renamed the class from
  classname to class.
- I have included the container-fluid which requires bootstrap 4 to make the menu wide. Otherwise there was no space to grow and it all came together. finally
- I have applied flex, to give similar entities to the menu and to the search field. You can do this by adding the "flex-grow-1" class to each of the tags of both entities. If you want one to be greater than the other, you can remove that class from a tag and see what happens.

You can see this code running on pure css + html in the next [link](https://www.codeply.com/p/Y78YVUVteb)

*Importante notice: I´m not familiar with react. So I changed from react code to pure thml + css code. But I´m assuming that you can understand as well.*

Good luck!